# Status of AudioWorkerNode in Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

According to the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#AudioWorker), the AudioWorker node should be functional. When I try to create it, the console throws back:

> TypeError: context.createAudioWorker is not a function.

My code:

```
var context;
if (typeof AudioContext !== 'undefined') {
  context = new AudioContext();
} 
else if (typeof webkitAudioContext !== 'undefined') {
  context = new webkitAudioContext();
} 
else {
  throw new Error('AudioContext not supported. :(');
}

var foo = context.createAudioWorker();
```

Am I doing this wrong, or has it not been implemented in FF/Chrome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has not been implemented yet in Chrome.  It's in the plan, but implementation has not yet started.

Comment: Ahh, got it. I take it, it's also not been implemented in Firefox?

Comment: If you get an error in FF, then I guess it hasn't been implemented yet either. I know it's being worked on, but I don't know what state it's in.

Comment: Oh, nobody is going to implement `AudioWorker`. It's been replaced by `AudioWorklet`. Both Chrome and Firefox have started implementation, but your guess is a good as mine on when there will be a usable version.